# How can I find the shortest distance from a point to a path over the surface of the earth

Tags: language-agnostic, maps

I have a list of lat/long points which form a path on the surface of the earth.
I have another point on the surface of the earth and I want to find the shortest distance from that point to a point that falls on the path.

While I could approximate the surface of the earth as a plane, accuracy is important.

The distance between points on the path could be anywhere from 1-1000m. The distance to the point not on the path is from 1-50m. The maximum acceptable error is 0.1m.

Any method of calculating this is acceptable, whether assuming a plane, sphere, or the real shape of the earth as long as the error would not exceed 0.1m for any point on land.

---

This question is marked language agnostic to encourage answers from people not familiar with the language used. The implementation will be in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to calculate the Great Circle Distance across the surface of the earth.  A Great Circle calculation permits the calculation of distance along the earth's surface between two arbitrary latitudes and longitudes.

A trivial example of a Great Circle calculation would be to migrate along the Earth's surface along the line of equator (zero degrees latitude).  Each degree of longitude of migration along that line (for instance from [0 deg N, 90 deg W] to [0 deg N to 91 deg W]) equates to 1/360th of 40,070km, or 111.306km.  Moving between two latitudes and two longitudes requires transformation of coordinates and is outside the scope of this quick note.

Summary and equations found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

The accuracy you are seeking of 0.1m requires further refinement; using a sphere to approximate the shape of the Earth will limit the accuracy to perhaps 0.5% (see paragraph from Wikipedia, below).  Put another way, a 0.5% error of two points 1000 km apart would be 5000 m.

A more formal and precise calculation will use the true shape of the earth, known as a geoid.  This is determined by gravitational measurements and is updated from time to time by the geodesic community.

It is possible to determine one's absolute position on Earth to +/- 0.1m (or better) with advanced GPS surveying techniques, such as RTK or satellite correction services (e.g. Omnistar), but determining the path distance to that accuracy is not the same thing.  A survey-quality receiver has corrections built into it for current geoids so that it can translate the lat/long/height calculation it makes using GPS signals to the current reference geoid used by the surveying / geodesic community.

You may not actually require 0.1m accuracy for your application; very few applications require 0.1m absolute accuracy over any distance except (for example) geographic determinations of movement in the Earth's surface.  Relative accuracy is more important; e.g. measuring the same point at different times. It is more important to know how much a seismic fault moved relative to its position yesterday or last week, or whether a critical point on a pipeline has moved 2 cm to the north in the past year.

I hope this helps.
Cheers
GP

Per Wikipedia:

*So long as a spherical Earth is assumed, any single formula for distance on the Earth is only guaranteed correct within 0.5% (though better accuracy is possible if the formula is only intended to apply to a limited area). [7]*

Comment: First of all, I'm aware that in most places GPS accuracy is ~10m, however there is a plan to upgrade the relevant area with SBAS with a target of <0.5m accuracy. Part of the reason I want high accuracy in this calculation is to not make the GPS value worse.

I am also aware of the great circle equations, however I wasn't sure how to find the shortest point between a point and a path. I may be missing something obvious, but these don't seem trivially equivalent.